# Difference in queries results with group by and without it

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
t1 with the following columns: `name | key | length`
t2 with the following columns: `name | country.`

I need to select all distinct keys with length>2000 group by country. So, I made

```
SELECT count(distinct key), country
from db.t1
inner join db.t2
on t1.name=t2.name
where length>2000
group by country;
```

But, when I make the query:

```
SELECT count(distinct key)
from db.t1
where Length>2000;
```

I am supposed to get equal results but I'm getting different results. For example, in the first query, I get 125494 and in the second I get: 121653.

What is the reason for this different results?? Knowing that there are some fields in the `country` are `''`. It seems to me they don't appear as a group and i counted them and found that they are 134 records. but I can't find out the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `key` is `UNIQUE` (in which case, why bother with the `DISTINCT` keywords?), there is no reason that your two queries should return the same results.

Suppose `t1` contains:

```
+------+-----+--------+
| name | key | length |
+------+-----+--------+
|    a |   x |   5000 |
|    b |   x |   5000 |
|    b |   y |   5000 |
|    c |   z |   5000 |
+------+-----+--------+
```

And `t2` contains:

```
+------+---------+
| name | country |
+------+---------+
|    a |      uk |
|    b |      fr |
|    c |      de |
+------+---------+
```

Then your queries will return:

1. First query:

   ```
   SELECT count(distinct key), country
   from db.t1
   inner join db.t2
   on t1.name=t2.name
   where length>2000
   group by country;
   ```

   Will yield:

   ```
   +---------------------+---------+
   | count(distinct key) | country |
   +---------------------+---------+
   |                   1 |      uk |
   |                   2 |      fr |
   |                   1 |      de |
   +---------------------+---------+
   ```
2. Second query:

   ```
   SELECT count(distinct key)
   from db.t1
   where Length>2000;
   ```

   Will yield:

   ```
   +---------------------+
   | count(distinct key) |
   +---------------------+
   |                   3 |
   +---------------------+
   ```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92400/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows in `t2` with the same `name` the join will be creating duplicates.

Comment: No. It is a unique value in t2 but many in t1. The two tables are connected as on-to-many.